# Recursion on strings - back to beginning of string?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, python-3.x

Given that in recursion you're using a divide-and-conquer method to break down problems into smaller pieces, how would you be able to read data from beginning of the problem, at the end of problem?

**Example**: I have a an `encrypt()` function that replaces characters in a string with characters 3 indices to the right:

`A` in string `"ABCDEF"` becomes `D` for example

So far I did it recursively up to the point where it stops when 3 indices to the right are undefined, but this leaves the last bit of the string the same as the original.

**Example**: `"ABCDEF"` becomes `"DEFDEF"`

Is there a way that I can pass the beginning of the string to the innermost functions during the recursive calls in an efficient way?

This is my code currently:

```
def shift_cipher_noloop(plain):

    encrypted = ""

    if(plain == ""):
        encrypted = ""

    else:
        if(len(plain) > 3):            
            temp_sub = plain[3]          
            encrypted = encrypted + temp_sub
            encrypted = encrypted + shift_cipher_noloop(plain[1:])

        else:
            temp_sub = plain[0] 
            encrypted = encrypted + temp_sub
            encrypted = encrypted + shift_cipher_noloop(plain[1:])

    return encrypted

x = "ABCDEFGHIJK"

y = shift_cipher_noloop(x)

print(y)
```

Comment: It will great if you post some code too.

Comment: pretty simple and clear I guess, the point is to avoid the use of the for loop

Comment: AHH i see what I could do, but then it involves using a third parameter, grab the first 3 chars then pass it on function by function, but that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: lol i know what I could do but it's going to be ugly - all sorts of ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this does not exactly solves your problem, but you may have to mould it a little bit to make it fit. As I see somewhere you want Recursion. I have just shown how you can move to the beginning, when you reach the end of the string.

Take the modulus of `i + 3` with the length of string to move to the beginning automatically: -

```
>>> my_str = "ABCDEF"
>>> length = len(my_str)

>>> for i in range(length):
        print my_str[(i + 3) % length],


D E F A B C
```

So, when `i = 3`, `i + 3 = 6`, and `6 % 6 = 0` -> back to the first character

---

If you want to use `Recursion`, here's your modified program: -

```
def shift_cipher_noloop(plain, i):

    if(plain == ""):
        return ""

    else:
        # Iterate with your string, moving first character to last on each iteration
        if len(plain) > 3 and i > 0: 
            return shift_cipher_noloop(plain[1:] + plain[0], i - 1)

        else:
            # else Will be executed when either len <= 3, or `i <= 0`.
            # when (i <= 0) is true, you have created a new string, 
            # with each character shifted by `original i` indices. 
            # So, just return it.

            return plain


x = "ABCDEF"
index_to_shift = 3
y = shift_cipher_noloop(x, len(x) - index_to_shift)

print(y)
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
DEFABC
```

I added one more parameter to your `method`, which I use to take the appropriate index. And also, I'm passing the complete string to the method each time moving the first character to the end.

Also, if the `len(plain) <= 3`, you can simply return the string.

Comment: def shift_cipher_noloop(plain):
    
    encrypted = ""
         
    if(plain == ""):
        encrypted = ""
        
    else:
        if(len(plain) > 3):            
            temp_sub = plain[3]          
            encrypted = encrypted + temp_sub
            encrypted = encrypted + shift_cipher_noloop(plain[1:])
            
        else:
            temp_sub = plain[0] 
            encrypted = encrypted + temp_sub
            encrypted = encrypted + shift_cipher_noloop(plain[1:])
    
    return encrypted
 
x = "ABCDEFGHIJK"

y = shift_cipher_noloop(x)

print(y)

Comment: @WilliamYang.. I added a modified versin of your code. Check it out whether you can understand it or not?

Comment: Can it be done with ONLY 1 param? that's the most elegant way I think, because the user may not supply i as an argument

Comment: @WilliamYang.. Umm. let me see.

Comment: @WilliamYang.. You have to pass one argument extra anyhow. How do you decide that the `value is 3`? You can also need to take every `4th character` instead of `3rd`?

Comment: @WilliamYang.. I modified the code a little bit, to pass the `index` instead of `0`. It will be mroe elegant. Now, user can pass by how much index he wants to shift his characters.

Comment: @WilliamYang. So, if you now want to shift character by 5 index. PAss 5 instead of 3

Comment: @WilliamYang.. Ah! fixed a little issue with the code. Please take the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use recursion, then I would use simple string methods.

```
def encrypt(text):
  return text[3:] + text[:3]
```

I also like Rohit Jain's answer a lot

Comment: The question is not about how to end up with the correct result, rather it is about how to solve this recursively.

Comment: You also could have said, "simply do `print "DEFABC"`" to get the correct output ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general there is the option of passing an additional parameter into the recursive function which is passed unchanged down into the deeper nests of the recursion.  You also can use inner functions which always can access the parameters of the outer ones:

```
def shift_cipher_noloop(original):
  def encrypt_recursion(plain):
    encrypted = ""
    if plain == "":
      encrypted = ""
    elif len(plain) > 3:
      encrypted += plain[3]
      encrypted += encrypt_recursion(plain[1:])
    else:
      encrypted += original[3-len(plain)]
      encrypted += encrypt_recursion(plain[1:])
    return encrypted
  return encrypt_recursion(original)

shift_cipher_noloop('abcdefghijklop')
'defghijklopabc'
```